# Muliple pie charts are not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to add multiple pie charts in a single page using d3 js.
The pie charts are loading when they are 2, but when I'm adding the 3rd pie chart the graph is not appending to the SVG.
[Here is my complete code.] 
My fiddel: http://www.jsfiddle.net/SampathPerOxide/xt0L1scu/10/

```
  var h = 600;
  var r = h / 2;
  var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

  var data = [{
        "label": "a",
        "value": 74
     },
     {
        "label": "b",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "b",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "d",
        "value": 12
     }
  ];
  var data1 = [{
        "label": "e",
        "value": 74
     },
     {
        "label": "f",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "g",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "h",
        "value": 12
     }
  ];

  var data2 = [{
        "label": "i",
        "value": 74
     },
     {
        "label": "j",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "k",
        "value": 7
     },
     {
        "label": "l",
        "value": 12
     }
  ];
  var colors = [
     'rgb(178, 55, 56)',
     'rgb(213, 69, 70)',
     'rgb(230, 125, 126)',
     'rgb(239, 183, 182)'
  ]
  nv.addGraph(function() {
     var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) {
           return d.label
        })
        .y(function(d) {
           return d.value
        })
        .color(colors)
        .showLabels(true)
        .labelType("percent");

     d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chart);

     d3.selectAll(".nv-label text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
           d.innerRadius = -450;
           d.outerRadius = r;
           return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        /* Alter CSS attributes */
        .style({
           "font-size": "1em"
        });

     d3.selectAll('.nv-series').each(function(d, i) {
        var group = d3.select(this),
           circle = group.select('circle');
        var color = circle.style('fill');
        circle.remove();
        var symbol = group.append('path')
           .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('square'))
           .style('stroke', color)
           .style('fill', color)
           .attr('transform', 'scale(1.5) translate(-2,0)')
     });
     return chart;
  });
  nv.addGraph(function() {
     var chartnew = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) {
           return d.label
        })
        .y(function(d) {
           return d.value
        })
        .color(colors)
        .showLabels(true)
        .labelType("percent");

     d3.select("#chartnew svg")
        .datum(data1)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chartnew);

     d3.selectAll(".nv-label text")
        /* Alter SVG attribute (not CSS attributes) */
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
           d.innerRadius = -450;
           d.outerRadius = r;
           return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style({
           "font-size": "1em"
        });

     d3.selectAll('.nv-series').each(function(d, i) {
        var group = d3.select(this),
           circle = group.select('circle');
        var color = circle.style('fill');
        circle.remove();
        var symbol = group.append('path')
           .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('square'))
           .style('stroke', color)
           .style('fill', color)
           .attr('transform', 'scale(1.5) translate(-2,0)')
     });
     return chartnew;
  });
  nv.addGraph(function() {
     var chartnewagains = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) {
           return d.label
        })
        .y(function(d) {
           return d.value
        })
        .color(colors)
        .showLabels(true)
        .labelType("percent");

     d3.select("#chartnewagain svg")
        .datum(data2)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chartnewagains);

     d3.selectAll(".nv-label text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
           d.innerRadius = -450;
           d.outerRadius = r;
           return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style({
           "font-size": "1em"
        });

     d3.selectAll('.nv-series').each(function(d, i) {
        var group1 = d3.select(this),
           circle = group.select('circle');
        var color = circle.style('fill');
        circle.remove();
        var symbol = group.append('path')
           .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('square'))
           .style('stroke', color)
           .style('fill', color)
           // ADJUST SIZE AND POSITION
           .attr('transform', 'scale(1.5) translate(-2,0)')
     });
     return chartnewagains;
  });
```

How can I add five pie charts on the same page using the above code?

Comment: Is it possible for you to improve the data structure such that the data for all five pie charts is in one array?

Comment: To add to the above comment and just to improve your code, you are using the d3 functions in a very WET (write everything twice) way. Why not create a function to draw the pie chart and call it by sending in parameters of the div name and the data and create a for loop with the data, data1, data2 in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that the solution suggested by Donat would work as the issue is not just the selections. I simplified the code to push the `data`, `data1`, `data2` into an array called `alldata`. This allowed me to create a `forEach` loop for each of the alldata loops and create a unified drawchart function which can draw the pie chart for the data.
After much troubleshooting, I discovered that the issue in the code was the appending of the data legends which was giving the issue. It seems the `circle.remove();` was causing the problem. I edited the code in the fiddle below which fixes the issue by removing the circle using a better selection.

Here is a complete working fiddle with improved code to make it easier to read:
https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/z1b2p7x3/

I hope this helps. Let me know if there is anything you need clarification on.

Comment: Perfect, iterating using the loop. Thanks for the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus your selection on each SVG.
So, first select current SVG:

```
const svg = d3.select("#chartnewagain svg")
```

then,

```
svg.selectAll(".nv-label text")
svg.selectAll('.nv-series')
```

Because, when you use d3.selectAll(".something") you are selecting everything with class .something (also in above SVG), and you don't want that.

Hope it helps :)

EDIT:
The issue is the

```
 d3.selectAll('.nv-series').each(function(d, i) {
  var group = d3.select(this),
    circle = group.select('circle');
  console.log(circle)  
  var color = circle.style('fill');  // error
...
```

Because when you do this first time then `'.nv-series'` is selected from first svg and everything is fine. Second time `'.nv-series'` is selected from first and second svg, and because you already deleted that circle in first, it throws an error when you what to get style from an element that it could not find with `circle = group.select('circle')`

So, solution is:

```
const svg = d3.select("#div_id svg")
...
svg.selectAll(".nv-label text")
...
svg.selectAll('.nv-series')
...
```

for every instance